# Help Sequelize array_append Data

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js, tracking, sequelize

Modelo:

```
sequelize.define('tracks', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        track: {
            type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSON),
            allowNull: true,
            defaultValue: []
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
```

Necesito hace lo siguiente en sequelize utilizando array_append

tengo la siguiente data :

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1583268240052,
    "lat": 37.33527476,
    "lng": -122.03254703,
    "speed": 1.67,
    "battery": -1,
    "timestamp": "2020-03-03T20:44:00.052Z"
}, {
    "id": 1583268245049,
    "lat": 37.33517518,
    "lng": -122.03255055,
    "speed": 2.41,
    "battery": -1,
    "timestamp": "2020-03-03T20:44:05.049Z"
}, {
    "id": 1583268249140,
    "lat": 37.33503868,
    "lng": -122.03265072,
    "speed": 6.37,
    "battery": -1,
    "timestamp": "2020-03-03T20:44:09.140Z"
}]
```

Pero para hacer un update al columa track requiero poner

```
Tracks.update({
    "track": app.sequelize.fn('array_append', app.sequelize.col('track'), data)
}, {
    where: {
        id: 1
    }
})
```

Claramente eso no funciona, ya que array_append espera un solo objeto pero NO un arreglo de objetos, es decir:

```
Tracks.update({
    "track": app.sequelize.fn('array_append', app.sequelize.col('track'), JSON.stringify({"id":1583268551161,"lat":37.36465673,"lng":-122.12512859,"speed":33.13,"battery":-1,"timestamp":"2020-03-03T20:49:11.161Z"}))
}, {
    where: {
        id: 1
    }
})
```

Ayuda requiero una solución optima para guardar los TRACK.

El sistema requiere que pueda agregar valores de track en un arreglo para ir guardandolos

hacer un concat de los valores como si fuera un arreglo, ocupa demasiado recurso de base de datos, ya que debe enviar en array completo cada vez que se actualiza los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione,

de todas formas si alguien le sirve como hacer un concat data de posgrest:

```
var location = JSON.stringify(req.body.location);
var last = JSON.stringify(app._.last(req.body.location));
var device = JSON.stringify(req.body.device);
var query = `UPDATE "tracks" SET "data_track"= array_cat("data_track", (WITH bu AS (SELECT json_array_elements('${location}') as bu) SELECT array_agg(bu) FROM bu)), "geoposition" = '${last}', "device" = '${device}', WHERE "id" = ${t.id};`;
return app.sequelize.query(query);
```

Ademas agrego la query de un concat Data de JSON values de un array type POSGREST:

```
UPDATE "tracks" 
SET "data_track"= array_cat("data_track", (WITH bu AS (SELECT json_array_elements('[{"lat":37.62605652,"lng":-122.42958496},{"lat":37.62605652,"lng":-122.42958496}]') as bu) 
    SELECT array_agg(bu) 
    FROM bu)) 
WHERE "id" = XXX;
```